Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "streamplatform-detail"
I'm starting to learn Django, and I'm trying to use HyperLinkSerializer. I've encountered this problem which has been quite bothersome since I can't find a way to solve it.
(https://i.sstatic.net/TMQVlzxJ.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/k3XV2Db8.png)(https://i.sstatic.net/JfKCMWC2.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/WxDMpahw.png)
I have tried changing the path name, but it didn't work. I have checked that this is a solution, but it doesn't work for me. Please help me.
